# Postgresql regexp_split_to_array NEGATION

Tags: regex, postgresql, regex-negation

So i can split a string into an array like this:

```
select regexp_split_to_array('Village at river nearby city' , ' at | nearby ')

-----------------------
{Village,river,city}
```

Easy.

But what if I want to negate this whole statement so the result is

```
{at,nearby}
```

I couldnt really find anything, because I coudnt find how to negate a list of words in regex...Any hints?

Comment: are you trying to split, because it sounds like your're trying to *match* words. by inverting the statement, you'd get, of course, *select regexp_split_to_array('Village at river nearby city' , ' village|river|city')*....?

Comment: no i really am trying to split

Comment: In some languages, if you include the string you're spliting with in parans then it'll return the matched split string in the array. like `regexp_split_to_array('Village at river nearby city' , '(at | nearby)')`